# AT&T Enhanced WebRTC + play .mp3

Tags: webrtc, att

I'm trying to use AT&T's WebRTC JavaScript development framework.  I don't see documentation for modifying a live call. Is it possible to modify a live call by playing an `.mp3` audio file?

http://developer.att.com/enhanced-webrtc

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with AT&T framework, but you can simply add another AUDIO tag that you will play during the call whenever you want. If you also want to interrupt the call, then you can simply mute the AUDIO/VIDEO tag with the remote stream attached.

Comment: Adrian,  Thanks for the info about Audio tags.  I'll look into that more.  

The AT&T webrtc solution is unique in that is includes the SIP-enabled telephone system to make traditional land line telephone calls.  The feature I'm looking for uses the browser to call a telephone and then play a .mp3 audio file over the telephone. The .mp3 audio is only heard on the telephone.

Comment: Then that it's sent through the stream. You can also look into WebAudio to combine two streams.